# Python Nested List

Tags: python

Hi I have to print each element in nested list using nested loops, but the code i wrote prints each element per line, but i need it to print all the items in the inner list per line.

```
new_grid=[['(a)', '(b)'], ['(c)','(d)'], ['(e)', '(f)']]
def print_newgrid():
    ''' 
    when printed it should look like:
    (a)(b)
    (c)(d)
    (e)(f)
    '''
    for i in new_grid:
        for j in i:
            print(j)
```

This prints each element per line, instead of two. Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you need to use nested lists, try:

```
>>> for i in new_grid:
...   for j in i:
...     print(j,end="")
...   print("")
...
(a)(b)
(c)(d)
(e)(f)
```

Or more simply:

```
>>> for i in new_grid:
...   print("".join(i))
...
(a)(b)
(c)(d)
(e)(f)
```

Since

Comment: i have to use nested lists

Comment: Both of @bernie's examples assume nested lists :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
print "\n".join([l[0] + l[1] for l in new_grid])
```

Will give

```
(a)(b)
(c)(d)
(e)(f)
```